# how to installing chrome on rhel5

Tags: google-chrome, rhel5

I want to install chrome on my rhel5 desktop but I am not able to install it.
I have created a repo google-chrome.repo, filled in the necessary commands (the link to this found everywhere on the internet)

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - 32-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Now when I try to do yum install google-chrome-stable, I get a dependency error.
What could be going wrong, I am not able to figure out. I have installed xdg-utils on my machine.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A alternate is s to download and untar a chrome.tar.gz file from whereever you can find on the internet. Create a desktop shortcut pointing to the chrome-wrapper file inside the chrome folder and you are done.

I still have not been able to figure out what was going wrong with my earlier approach(as mentioned in the question). I scourged through the internet to find the solution to my above question but could not find one. A lot of people are facing this problem and there are not any working solutions. To answer this question here and then voting for it should get it up as of the first google results. An answer to this question should help out a lot of people.